# Similar memory access for ldr and ldrd on Cortex-A9 only without cache

Tags: caching, arm, benchmarking, timing

I'm benchmarking an i.MX6 Dual processor based on the ARM Cortex-A9 with 4*256MB DDR3 SDRAM.
One of the test consists on measuring timings for copying data, with different data sizes : 8-bits, 16-bits, 32-bits and 64-bits.

First, I run the test with L1 and L2 cache enabled. The results are the following (we copy 32 768 datas) :

- 8-bits :  206 us
- 16-bits : 472 us
- 32-bits : 954 us
- 64-bits : 1 520 us

Right now, everything seems okay with these results. However, if I disable the cache, here's my new results  :

- 8-bits :  2 292 us
- 16-bits : 4 556 us
- 32-bits : 9 101 us
- 64-bits : 9 162 us

It appears that copying 32-bits or 64-bits datas takes approximately the same amount of time, while it should be the double for 64-bits if I'm not wrong? The code I used is the same for both tests, and since they are executed 256 times each, I suppose I didn't stumbled on some worst/best case problem.

Secondly, I then ran the benchmark with unordered copy, and in that case I saw a similar speed for each iteration regardless of the data size.

I would be interested in knowing why do I have such results, do you have any idea?

Comment: Hang on, those times don't look right - copying one byte at a time is ~7x faster than copying 8 bytes at a time? Or do you mean the total data size is changed as well, i.e. the former is copying 32KB while the latter is copying 256KB, in which case it's not really an apples-to-apples comparison and somewhat harder to reason about.

Comment: @Notlikethat Yeah so I fixed the spelling, I used "data block" which was pretty confusing I guess. I'm accessing 32 768 addresses if you prefer, whatever the length of my datas is.

Comment: OK, if it's a constant _number_ of load/store transactions, then the question is really why the sub-32-bit transactions are quicker. Assuming these numbers represent a straight linear copy, the next thing I'd try would be using different strides - at a wild guess, it could be something like your DRAM being 32 bits wide, so for, say, sequential 16-bit accesses every other one hits a still-open row and returns that much more quickly.

Comment: @Notlikethat Okay so I ran the benchmark with unordered copy, and now I have a similar speed for each iteration. I guess you were right about the still-open rows, so I did get faster access because (or thanks more likely?) to that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Google *ARM write buffer* for a reason.

Comment: You can probably further narrow down potential memory vs. store buffer effects by testing different combinations of patterns, e.g. load sequentially but store on an 8-byte stride to prevent merging. I had a look at the DDR controller chapter of the i.MX6D TRM in the hope of writing up a plausible answer, but it doesn't really detail the internal buffering (plus I started getting a bit out of my depth as I'm not that much of a hardware guy...) In short, there's a lot of things throughout the whole system all interacting and it's complicated.